# Getting an action after text is pasted into a JTextComponent (Java)

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextcomponent

This really puzzles me.

I have a `JTextComponent` for which I've added a right-click cut\copy\paste menu using a JPopupMenu and `DefaultEditorKit.Cut\Copy\PasteAction()`.

```
JMenuItem cutItem = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction());
JMenuItem copyItem = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction());
JMenuItem pasteItem = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());
```

For each action I've added an action listener which grabs the JTextComponent's text, which I want to use in a function.

```
final ActionListener textFieldListener = new ActionListener() {
@Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){someGlobalFunction(textComponent.getText());
}
};
```

...

```
cutItem.addActionListener(textFieldListener );
copyItem.addActionListener(textFieldListener );
pasteItem.addActionListener(textFieldListener );
```

However, the only text I can get hold on is the String which it was *before* I cut\paste into the component, not after.

Is there any obvious solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the code in the actionPerformed() method in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...), This will add the code to then end of the EDT so it should execute after the cut/copy/paste commands.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you don't listen your text field, you listen the menu :-)

Put a listener on your text field, or on the document of your text field, or perhaps a FilterDocument, or even your own document.